# Is there a way to make this radial-gradient line darker?

Tags: css, radial-gradients

Even though it's black, it shows as a light gray. i don't want the dots bigger.

https://jsfiddle.net/bek17q3t/1/

```
body,html
{
  background-color: #e7e6e6;
  height: 100%;
}
div
{
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  left: 30px;
  width: .25em;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle closest-side,#000000 calc(100% - .25em),transparent 100%);
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-size: .25em .75em;
}
```

Comment: Change the `calc` line from `(100% - .25em)` to `(100% - .1em)` ?

Comment: @scoopzilla: Why haven't you posted that as an answer? I think you should.

Comment: @Harry because it's not correct. try it

Comment: @DonRhummy: I did and the circle did become darker. Wait, I'll give the link. (*Edit:* [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/bek17q3t/4/) is the link. I see darker black dots. Is this not what you want? If this is not, can you explain further how it should be?)

Comment: @Harry you're right! odd, it wasn't working for me before. must've had something else in there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
body,html
{
  background-color: #e7e6e6;
  height: 100%;
}
div
{
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  left: 30px;
  width: .25em;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle closest-side,#000000 calc(100% - .1em),transparent 100%);
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-size: .25em .75em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  </div>
```

Change the calculation.

Comment: If you don't mind adding, you may want to say that *the color is gray in the original snippet because it is fading between black (first color) and transparent (second color) and the period for which the color is black is smaller. By increasing the color stop point (changing `100% - .25em` to `100% - .1em`) for the first color, we are making the color remain as black for a longer period and thus the dot looks black in color.*